# How install qt libraries near to executable file

Tags: qt, cmake, qt5

There was such a problem: using cmake to install the compiled executable in a certain directory, along with all the dependent libraries (qt), so that later this folder could be simply transferred to another computer, with the same architecture (and installed packages, like built-essential). And do it on two systems: linux & windows. And there are two problems:

1. what are the dependencies of Qt libraries and how to identify them with cmake (if it possible)?
2. when using `install(FILES $<TARGET_FILE:Qt5::some_packet> DESTINATION bin)` on Linux, the following libraries will be copied: `libQt5some_packet.so.5.11.1` and when you try to start the program, it will immediately declare that it cannot find the corresponding libraries. And the command `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/install path/bin` haven't any result.

UDP i find how fix problem 2:

```
install(FILE $<TARGET_SONAME_FILE:Qt::some_package> DESTINATION bin)
```

but first problem (for windows) is open.

Comment: Have you read the [Qt deployment guide](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/deployment.html)?

Comment: @MrEricSir in progress. I don't understand which libraries and how I get this by cmake.

Comment: Qt has a lot of dependencies based on which modules you are shipping, what features in those modules are enabled and what the target platform is. The deployment tool that @MrEricSir suggested is your best bet but my past (3-4 years ago) experience with it was that it didn't do the complete job and in the end I still had to do a lot of manual labour.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dependency Walker to get the complete list of dll dependencies